# When I try to store a character in an array, the array fills with numbers instead c++

Tags: c++, arrays, character, ifstream

I'm very new to c++ so all of this is very confusing to me. I'm reading characters from a file using ifstream.get and storing the values in a 2d integer array. The file is just a 9x9 grid of numbers 1 through 9.

So I read the character and when I hover over it in debug mode to see the value, I can see the number represented as a character but also a number written next to it. Apparently this is the address or something. When I print the character to the console, everything is fine. But when I try to store the character in the 2d integer array, it stores the address (or whatever it is) instead.

```
void Grid::LoadGrid(const char filename[])
{
    ifstream inputFile(filename);
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
             char c;
             inputFile.get(c);
             cout << c;
             m_grid[x][y] = c;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `m_grid`? Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  `int m_grid[9][9];`

Comment: Do you have a chapter in your C++ textbook that explains the ASCII character set? Look up the ASCII code for the character `0`, and everything should become crystal clear.

Comment: @henry1000 [edit] your question please, read the article linked above before.

Comment: I think the issue is due to inputFile.get(), you need to pass a pointer to your char. so try to update with inputFile.get(&c);  Be carefull, you can have a unwanted '\r\n' (classic issue in C, I don't know it's the case in C++)

Comment: Knowing that it's storing the ASCII code instead doesn't really help though. It's still not doing what I need it do to

Comment: @AntoineLaps thanks for the response but unfortunately that didn't work. "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Comment: @henry1000 *"Knowing that it's storing the ASCII code instead doesn't really help though"* It really should. Understanding the cause of a problem is a huge step in the process of fixing a problem.

Comment: @henry1000 sorry, I miss read the doc, I'm mainly a C dev, and scanf, require an variable pointer
 I also miss read you're comment. If it's only a print problem, et's because you don't have a trailling 0 after you're array, try to update you're array with m_array[10][10], and add a 0(value not char) at end of each line

Comment: Or you could have just said `c - '0'` would have done the trick

Comment: @AntoineLaps no worries man

Comment: @AntoineLaps "*I think the issue is due to inputFile.get(), you need to pass a pointer to your char*" - that is incorrect. [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) has an overload that takes a `char&` reference for a single char. The overloads that take a `char*` pointer require a buffer and a size, eg `inputFile.get(&c, 1)`. The original code is perfectly fine, I think the OP just doesn't understand what is actually happening with the `char`->`int` conversion

Comment: @henry1000 "*Or you could have just said `c - '0'` would have done the trick*" - Nothing in your original question indicates that you are trying to read single-digit integers from the file and store equivalent integers into your matrix, ie reading `'1'` and storing `1`, so why do you think anyone would have thought to suggest `c - '0'` to you? You left out important details in your question, like, you know, the actual input and the desired result.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "The file is just a 9x9 grid of numbers 1 through 9" "When I print the character to the console, everything is fine. But when I try to store the character in the 2d integer array, it stores the address (or whatever it is) instead."

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `int` values because you are trying to store `char` in an `int` array, which leads to conversion of `char` to `int` (`ASCII` value of `char`). So the int values is basically the `ASCII` value of the character `'0'`, `'1'`, etc.

If you want to store characters then just store them inside a char array:

```
char m_grid[9][9];
```

But still if you need to store the data in an int array, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int m_grid[9][9];

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            char c;
            inputFile.get(c);
            std::cout << c;
            m_grid[x][y] = (int)c - '0';
        }
        inputFile.get(); // This will skip '\n'
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisAndrieux for the info. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`int ic = c - '0';`

For anyone wondering how to fix this